# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xbf7ffffc) GMTOAuth2

Tags: ios

I am using GMTOAuth2 in an application with one viewController and it works fine, Then I add same code to another application that contains more viewControllers, It loads the webView with textfields for username and password but if I click on anything in this view it crashes with Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xbf7ffffc) with void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode in the console. My code for authorization part looks like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = nil;
    auth = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                             clientID:kMyClientID
                                                         clientSecret:kMyClientSecret];
    if (auth)
    {
        [auth authorizeRequest:nil
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(authentication:request:finishedWithError:)];
    }


}


- (void)signInToGoogle {
    [self signOut];

    NSString *keychainItemName = kKeychainItemName;

    NSString *scope = @"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://docs.google.com/feeds";
    NSString *clientID = kMyClientID;
    NSString *clientSecret = kMyClientSecret;

    if ([clientID length] == 0 || [clientSecret length] == 0) {
        NSString *msg = @"The sample code requires a valid client ID and client secret to sign in.";
        [self displayAlertWithMessage:msg];
        return;
    }

    SEL finishedSel = @selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:);

    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]     initWithScope:scope
                                                                                              clientID:clientID
                                                                                          clientSecret:clientSecret
                                                                                  keychainItemName:keychainItemName
                                                                                  finishedSelector:finishedSel];
                                                                                          delegate:self
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:^{}];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];


}

- (void)authentication:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
           request:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
     finishedWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"error!");
    } else {
        [self isAuthorizedWithAuthentication:auth];
        self.auth = auth;    
    }
}
```

And copied the same class from first application to second one, and made exactly same nib file.